# Avoid Gradle to call child task automatically?

Tags: gradle, circular-dependency, build.gradle

I have *:myRootProject:myTask* that is adding automatically a dependency on *:myRootProject:myChildProject:myTask*

I do not want Gradle to do that, because *myChildProject:myTask* depends on *myRootProject:myTask* and I get a circular dependency

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Any reproducible sample?

Comment: usually gradle does not automatically create those task dependencies. as opal mentioned, a reproducible snippet would be helpful here.